# How to set general rewrite rule for many subdomains?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to set rewrite rule in .htaccess with this criteria:

I put http://xxx.domain.com/yyy/zzz --> I get http://www.domain.com/xxx/yyy/zzz

BUT(!): In address field of browser will stay origin URL (left one)

I need to set this for many dynamic generated subdomains, I need general rule.

Anyone help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: Additional info: depth of subdirs are variable (/xxx/yyy/zzz or /xxx/yyy/zzz/111 or /xxx/yyy/zzz/111/222 etc..)

Comment: Have you not tried anything?

Comment: Yes i tried many, f.e.

Comment: RewriteRule    http://(.*).domain.com/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1/$2/$3

Comment: but not work nothing

Comment: You will need to add the [proxy flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) to your rule in order to have the URL remain the same.